# Open tree view rows in different tab

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have an custom Odoo module where I have a view that displays a field in a table (tree view) by using a widget `many2many`:

```
<page string="Órdenes a costear">
    <field string="Órdenes a costear" name="orders" widget="many2many" />
</page>
```

Displaying this:

[image]

When I click on a table row, a pop up appears with the form view of the selected row. What I would like to do is to either:

- Ideally, open the form view of the selected row in a different tab, OR
- If the above not possible, make the rows not clickable at all

I have tried to do this by setting the options field to:

```
options="{'no_create_edit': True, 'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}"
```

But no luck there.

Do you know if this is possible by using model or view attributes like `options`? Otherwise, do you know if inheriting and modifying an existing widget would help here?

I'd like to avoid creating a widget from scratch just to do this.

Comment: have you tried editable="bottom" , along with no_create = True?@damores

Comment: yes try as per above comment

Comment: Tried it right now, not working for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: yes....@damores